# Datebox : hideInput causes Header to disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, datebox

on JQueryMobile Datebox setting `hideInput: "true"` causes the Header to disappear?

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="roster" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header" class="tb">
        <h1>Roster</h1>
        <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "cal box", "hideInput": "true"}'>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b" id="callback">  
          <!-- CONTENT LOADED VIA AJAX -->          
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
          <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Header is visible when I remove `"hideInput": "true"` but gone if I just change to "false"

Comment: still need the link to open calendar?

Comment: resolved with a series of other answers, see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843871/location-reload-in-jquery-1-8-not-default-one