# location.reload in JQuery 1.8 not default #one

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a previous version of JQuery or JQTouch I called `location.reload()` to reload the full single page. I'm having an issue with the reload staying on the same #abc page of my project… I need it to reload to the default #one of single page project

Comment: `location.reload()` has nothing to do with jQuery. It's a built-in browser operation.

Comment: ok, shouldn't the browser reload to the default page and not retain #xyz?

Comment: try `window.location.reload()` ?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet: Umm.. that's the same as `location.reload()`.

Comment: `location.reload()` will reload whatever URL is in the address bar.  If it has a hash (`#abc`) in the URL, that's what page it's gonna load.

Comment: Thanks so much, that did it… I didn't know the window would remove the hash.

Comment: @RocketHazmat right, check my posted answer instead.. jeje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var custom_reload = function(){
    window.location.hash = '';
    window.location.reload();
}
```

And then just:

```
custom_reload();
```

Comment: so the `window.location.hash = '#page2';` would redirect to that hash?

Comment: Actually I don't think so, if that's where you want to direct user try `window.location.href = '/page.php#page2'`